# Junit 5 gradle plugin not found

Tags: gradle, plugins, junit5

Try to use junit 5 with gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
...
```

Error:

```
Plugin with id 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin' not found.
```

Gradle version 4.0. What is wrong?

Comment: It all looks good. The configuration looks fine. Don't you have any problems with internet connection/proxy settings?

Comment: internet working fine

Comment: Can you add `--stacktrace` to build arguments and post it?

Comment: have the same problem

Answer (score 6):

Since version **4.6** for **Gradle**, there is no need for plugins anymore

**Gradle** supports **Junit5** natively just do:

```
dependencies {       
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion"

    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter', 'junit-vintage'
    }
}
```

Comment: It says "Could not get unknown property 'test' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler." for Gradle 4.9

Comment: it now says: "Could not find method test() for arguments [build_bqn8c5oncbrv33jyn5ld7eddp$_run_closure3@2ec4a0f9] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: show your code in the code bucket the whole build.gradle the above code works just fine, you maybe missing the java plugin?

Comment: I'm using android plugin, might that be an issue?

Answer (score 5):

You have to include a `repositories` section outside the `buildscript` block as well:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you placing the above code in a separate file that you are then including in the main `build.gradle` via `apply from: ...`? If so, you may be running up against a bug in Gradle where a plugin id cannot be used in external scripts. Instead, you have to specify the fully qualified class name.

More info:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1262

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-include-buildscript-block-from-external-gradle-script/7016

Comment: That helped. The line that worked for me: `apply plugin: org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin.JUnitPlatformPlugin`